# cannot access a disposed object UserManager in asp.net mvc core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity

I have following code in my service that should create UserManager instance

```
public class SubscriptionService : ISubscriptionService
{

    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return userManager;  

        }
        private set { userManager = value; }
    }

    public SubscriptionService(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,   
        StripeCustomerService customerService, 
        StripeSubscriptionService subscriptionService)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.customerService = customerService;
        this.subscriptionService = subscriptionService;
    }

    public SubscriptionService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }
```

When userManager is called first time inside class, it works but second call returns an error "`cannot access a disposed object UserManager`"

I'm consuming SubscriptionService class in my controller with:

```
public ISubscriptionService SubscriptionService
{
    get
    {
        return subscriptionService ?? new SubscriptionService(_userManager);
    }
    private set
    {
        subscriptionService = value;
    }
}
```

Can someone point me where i'm wrong with this and how to fix it?

I'm using ASP.NET Core 1.0

edit: here's user manager inspected right after first execution in function

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with second call? Is that the next http request?

Comment: No, i'm calling userManager.FindByNameAsync() then do something with user and finally call userManager.UpdateAsync(). second call throws an exception..

Comment: And the userManager references a disposed object, not something in the implementation of UpdateAsync()?

Comment: I bet you're having a [Captive Dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/). Besides that, I see multiple flaws in what you are doing. First of all, [don't have multiple constructors](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97). Second, don't have settable properties for your dependencies.

Comment: @onedevteam.com How did you solve it. I am having exact same issue.